# Converting spaces to int in VB causes error

Tags: vb.net

We have an old application written in VB that parses a file. I get an error when trying to convert spaces to an integer. I think the program should just continue and assign 0 for **LoadNumber** . Could this be related to an old VB library file? Because I ran the code in a VB console app in Visual Studio and it seems to run fine. How do I find out what is causing the issue?

```
Overridable Sub Parse01()
BOLNumber = InputLine.Substring(12, 20)
SourceNumber = InputLine.Substring(2, 5)

Carrier = InputLine.Substring(116, 6)
Driver = InputLine.Substring(37, 15)
DateFinished = InputLine.Substring(77, 8)
TimeFinished = InputLine.Substring(87, 2) & ":" & InputLine.Substring(89, 2)
Finish_DateTime = DateFinished.ToString & " " & TimeFinished
TruckNumber = InputLine.Substring(124, 5)

'LoadNumber = InputLine.Substring(107, 7)

Dim loadNumberAsInt As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(InputLine.Substring(107, 7), loadNumberAsInt) Then
    LoadNumber = InputLine.Substring(107, 7)
Else
    LoadNumber = "0"
End If

CustomerNumber = InputLine.Substring(57, 15)
TimeIn = InputLine.Substring(91, 4)

End Sub
```

Error

```
Could not process the file for shipper:0001 - Conversion from string "               " to type 'Integer' is not valid. -    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
       at Program.Reader.Parse01()
       at Program.Reader.ProcessRecords()
       at Program.Reader.ParseInputLine()
       at Program.Reader.Parse(String Path)
       at Program.Reader.ProcessFile(String Source, String Number, EDI_File_Reader EDI_R)
```

Comment: Before  `Dim loadNumberAsInt As Integer` you have multiple assignments to variables. Is it possible that one of these is an `Integer`? Change `Option Strict Off` to `On`.

Comment: I checked and none of those is an integer. They are all declared as a string.

Comment: If `LoadNumber` is an integer, then you should just pass that to `Integer.TryParse` instead of trying to assign it from a string.  You could reverse the logic of the `If` or you could make an empty `If` body and retain the `Else`.  Also, change to `LoadNumber = 0` (drop the quotes).

Comment: Run the program in debug mode and the exception will yield the line number where the problem occurs.

Comment: @null: So every variable in this method, including `LoadNumber` and `TimeIn` are strings? Use the debugger and skip through the method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is with `CustomerNumber = InputLine.Substring(57, 15)` The error shows an string that is 15 in length. Is CustomerNumber a string? This is where you need a TryParse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 15 spaces in the error message. So the problem will be somewhere else.
 I think it could be here.

```
CustomerNumber = InputLine.Substring(57, 15)
```

Maybe CustomerNumber should be an string. If not, then I suggest you do a TryParse on this one also.

Comment: CustomerNumber is also a string. But good point about the 15 spaces, I am going to look into that.

Comment: @null what are the integer properties in there? Seems like even LoadNumber is a string since you put "0" in it. Or do any of these properties do conversion.

Comment: There are no integer variables other than loadNumberAsInt.

Comment: @null then the error makes no sense based on the current code. Maybe an override of Parse01 or a property doing some extra work when the value is set.

Comment: You are right. I was looking at the wrong Parse01 method. Thank you.